# Converting Java to C++

Tags: java, c++

I'm new to C++ so I'm having trouble converting this into C++. Is there examples that I could see how a C++ arraylist looks. I know java has several classes that can be made but in C++ how would that be made would it be all under one .cpp file.

```
public class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Inventory netFlix = new Inventory();

    netFlix.add( "Prince of Persia",     140);
    netFlix.add( "Clash of Titans",      223);
    netFlix.add( "Avatar",               353);
    netFlix.add( "Inception",            460);
    netFlix.add( "Resident Evil",        105);
    netFlix.add( "Devil",                624);
    netFlix.add( "Memento",              117);
    netFlix.add( "D2: The Mighty Ducks", 508);
    netFlix.add( "The Lord of the Rings",910);
    netFlix.add( "The Uninvited",        120);
```

Comment: System.out.println("The Terminator")

Comment: Nice code. Is there a question too?

Comment: Please follow [general](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) question [guidelines](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10812), state any special restrictions, show what you've tried so far, and ask about what specifically is confusing you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vector` is probably your friend. Look here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/vector/

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this thread. http://www.horstmann.com/ccj2/ccjapp3.html

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Movie {
  std::string name;
  int score;

  Movie(std::string name, int score) : name (name), score (score) {}
};

int main() {
  using namespace std;
  typedef vector<Movie> Inventory;

  Inventory movies;
  movies.push_back(Movie("The Lord of the Rings",  910));
  movies.push_back(Movie("HHGTTG",                  42));

  for (Inventory::const_iterator x = movies.begin(); x != movies.end(); ++x) {
    cout << x->name << " = " << x->score << '\n';
  }

  return 0;
}
```